# Not able to complete challenge for final module of process builder

Tags: process-builder

I am not able to finish final module(Test your process) of process builder trailhead.Its showing me error message:
Step not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Account number must be 8 characters long: []

But i have checked account number is having length of 8 chars as per validation rule.
please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Validation Rule on Account Object and then try again it will do the trick

Comment: Thanks Amit. This want working in lightning platform for some reason. But i tried disabling it on classic version and it worked. :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Amit. Working in lightning.